# Asp.net MVC azure ad group identification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm currently finishing my website in ASP.NET MVC with azure AD login.

For this website, some pages are only accessible by admins. For this, I made a new group that's named `testAdmins` and when I check if the user can access to a page, I use this :

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

if (principal.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "groups" && x.Value == "id of testAdmins")){ //code }
```

And it's working fine with my user witch is in this group.

But when I change the id of `testAdmins` with the value of the real group of admins (`Admins`) I'm going to use when the site will be deployed and witch I'm not in, the server is not showing anything for 40 sec and then I got this message :

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

Can someone explain me what's going on ?

Thanks in advance

PS : I made some more test... When my user is in the group it works fast but when it's not it takes 2 min and do the error message... if someone as no idea what is the problem, did anyone have a way to make different access from user wich are in a special group from Azure Active Directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the whole stacktrace and relevant source code line (the full stacktrace includes file names and line numbers!). The issue you are facing is very common for on-boarding developers (on-boarding to ASP.NET 4.0+).

Your project is based on the default project template for ASP.NET 4.0 (or later), which by default creates the website with "Local User Accounts". This template creates an Entity Framework db context and local models for the user authentication / authorization. This also creates some settings in your web.config to define connectin strings (or instruct the default one) for the EF.

On top of that template you added the neccessery Azure AD authentication details - either through the right click menu (Configure Azure AD Authentication - available in VS 2015) or manually by including a bunch of NuGet packages. Thus you (without knowing) created a nasty mix of FBA (Forms Based Authentication) - dictated by the local accounts, and OpenID Connect - dictated by Azure AD authentication.

The SQL Server error comes from that FBA (or local user accounts setting) config. And there is no easy way to remove it.

Because I see you are just playing around and testing out things, I would warmly recommend that you start over with a new project and be careful by your second step of the wizard (available in both VS 2013 and VS 2015) - Click on "change authentication" and chose "No authentication":

[image]

On this clean project, you can add your Azure AD authentication and everything will work and you will not see any SQL Server Errors (well it depends how you configure your Azure AD Auth - some of the wizzards - namely the one of Multi-tenant also creates EF context).

Comment: Omg really ? oO Are you sure ? Because It's works well if I'm in the group... Maybe he is just looking too far and get a time out because `principal.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "groups" && x.Value == "id of testAdmins")` is too big ?

Comment: Claims Property of the ClaimsPricipal is a Collection Property which is initialized by the OpenID Connect Owin middleware. There is no access to any database when you do query this Property. And it cannot be so big to cause timeout. Go and check out the documentation regarding ClaimsPrincipal and its Claims property, mrPixel! You can also do some JustDecompile to examine the ClaimsPrincipal type and see with your own eyes that there are no calls to DB.

Comment: Ok Thanks for you help !